# Prevent the timer from pausing in the background mode

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, momentjs, ionic3

I have a timer in my Ionic3 application. The timer runs perfectly with a `setInterval`, but when I close the App into the sleep mode, the timer stops to run. After bringing my App again to the fourground, the timer continue - but he starts at the place where it paused before.

how can I prevent the timer from pausing If I background the App?

**My component**

```
time: any;

displayTime() {
  this.time = moment().hour(0).minute(0).second(this.counter++).format('HH : mm : ss');
}

startTime() {
  if(this.runClock == null) {
    this.runClock = setInterval(() => {
      this.displayTime();
    },1000)
  }
}
```

In my HTML I call `{{ time }}`.

Plugins like https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/ will not work, because the App Store will reject Apps using this plugin.

Any other ideas?

Comment: http://www.codingandclimbing.co.uk/blog/ionic-2-simple-countdown-timer

Comment: How does this solve the issue with background mode?

Comment: By 'starts at the place where it paused' do you mean that moment() doesn't return proper time or that there's a short glitch of previous time?

Comment: The time is wrong, yes. Example: I start the time -> I wait until 00:02:30 -> I close the app in the background --> I wait 5 minutes -> I start the app from the background in the fourground -> Timer returns maybe 00:02:41 .....

Comment: And then 00:02:42 and 00:02:43, right?

Comment: absolutely right, yes. :)

Comment: I have a couple of apps that use this plugin that are on Apple's app store. They will only reject if it you don't include an explanation in the plist file for why you need to use it. They will also want it to be a valid reason so it doesn't drain the battery without good cause. They don't just blanket reject the app because of the plugin.

Comment: Best Solution is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088711/timerssetinterval-in-ionic-apps-go-to-sleep-after-some-time-in-the-background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the application that runs in background mode can be [rejected in App Store](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements) (and there would be a good reason for this, because nobody needs an app that drains the battery for nothing), this should be done without relying on `setInterval` counter and background mode:

```
startMoment = moment();

displayTime() {
  this.time = moment.utc( moment().diff(this.startMoment) ).format('HH : mm : ss');
}
```

Comment: oh, very great way! But my timer does not start... my code: `startAt = moment();` and: `if(!this.runClock) {
      this.runClock = true;

      this.startAt = moment();
      this.time = moment( moment().diff(this.startAt) ).format('HH : mm : ss');

      this.content.resize();
    }` the timer shows from beginning "01 : 00 : 00" and this remains.

Comment: The code in the question assumes that `startTime` method stays unchanged. You still need to update `time` every second with setInterval.

Comment: I did, the counter works now. But the counter begins with hour 01. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I guess it doesn't take timezone into account. I'd generally suggest moment.utc instead to avoid this. Added this to the answer.

Comment: @EstusFlask sir how to call function inside that?

Comment: @Kapilsoni I'm not sure what you mean. `moment()` is a function and it's called there.

Comment: sir actually before i called function inside setInterval but in background mode after few second function is stop execution.i do if user is in background and i have called 1 function in background and pass lat and long to backend  every second.tell me sir how to do this?

Comment: @Kapilsoni If the app stops, you can't. The answer explains how negative effects of that can be avoided for the case that OP had. Your case is different. You need https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/

Comment: @EstusFlask: sir i have used above plugin but setInterval not fire in background only fire 3 second?

Comment: @Kapilsoni Then I'd say that the plugin doesn't work as intended. Consider asking your own question that shows how exactly you use the plugin. I currently don't use Ionic and likely unable to help you with solving the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198360/discussion-between-kapil-soni-and-estus-flask).